# Flex 4.6 spark FormItem inner gap (padding) cannot be removed?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, padding, flex-spark, flex4.6

Working with Flex 4.6 spark forms, i encountered strange behaviour:

FormItem element ALWAYS has inner gap (padding), which cannot be removed.

Red area on image ilustrates the **unwanted GAP** that i cannot manage to get rid of.
Blue border represents `Form` component. Grey border (thin) represents `FormItem` component.

[image]

FormItem has no `padding` or `gap` property.

This is the code for image above:

```
    <s:Form id="form">
        <s:layout>
            <s:FormLayout gap="0"
                          paddingBottom="50"
                          paddingTop="0"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:FormItem width="100%" label="RC">
            <s:TextInput id="myTextInput" width="215"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
```

When developing for mobile, you want to make best use of every pixel on your screen. This is unacceptable for me since i want to have several `TextInput` fields and having this gap will waste lots of space...

So my question is, can the red GAP be removed? I want my `FormItem` to have `padding 0` - meaning `TextInput` border will touch `FormItem` border...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well things like that are usually managed by the skin of the component, so what you have to do is to provide your own skin for your `FormItem` components. The easiest way to do it is to copy the skin provided by Adobe and make some tweaks that'll accomplish what you require. Most of all you have to set `baseline` to `maxAscent:0` on `row1` `ConstraintRow` and `bottom` to `row1:0` on `sequenceLabelDisplay`, `labelDisplay` and `contentGroup` components.